# Can I associate multiple upload fields to chosen array keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Don't know if my question is that what I would say, but I will try.
I'm using 8 file-uploadforms which are chained to other form-fields. E.g.:

```
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f1" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f2" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f3" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f4" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f5" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f6" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f7" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[]" id="f8" />
```

The upload of all works fine. The Array will output correctly:

```
[upload] => Array
( 
   [0] => filefirst.pdf 
   [1] => filetwo.pdf 
   [2] => filethree.pdf
   [3] => filefourth.pdf
   [4] => filefife.pdf
   [5] => filesix.pdf
   [6] => fileseven.pdf
   [7] => fileeight.pdf
)
```

What I trying to do is that, when I upload only f2 and f6 to make the keys associated e.g.:

```
[upload] => Array
( 
   [1] => filetwo.pdf 
   [5] => filesix.pdf
)
```

Is that possible? How?

Comment: It would be possible if you specified the keys. As in have `name=fileInput[1], name=fileInput[2] ...`.

Comment: i tryed that as first :(

Answer (score 0):

Add `id`s as keys of input fields array:

```
<input type="file" name="fileInput[f1]" id="f1" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[f2]" id="f2" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[f3]" id="f3" />
<input type="file" name="fileInput[f4]" id="f4" />
<!-- etc -->
```